# Escrever um documento php dentro de um bloco de php

Tags: php

Boa Noite,

Bom a minha dúvida é a seguinte pretendo escrever um documento php dentro de um bloco de php.

Por exemplo:

```
<?php

$cn = "texto.php";

file_put_contents($cn, '');

// Inicio Codigo que queria que fosse escrito
$conteudo = "<?php

require_once('./data_classes/server-data.php_data_classes-core.php.php');
require_once('./data_classes/server-data.php_data_classes-session.php.php');

$select = "SELECT * FROM cms_settings WHERE variable='client_ip'";
$result = mysql_query($select);
while($l = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$cliendfgtip = $l['value'];
}

$select = "SELECT * FROM cms_settings WHERE variable='client_port'";
$result = mysql_query($select);
 while($l = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$clienghjport = $l['value'];
}

mysql_query("UPDATE users SET auth_ticket = '', auth_ticket = '".GenerateTicket()."', ip_last = '', ip_last = '".$remote_ip."' WHERE id = '".$my_id."'") or die(mysql_error());

$ticketsql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '".$my_id."'") or die(mysql_error());
$ticketrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($ticketsql);

$client_port = mysql_fetch_assoc($client_port = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cms_settings WHERE variable = 'client_port'"));
$client_mus = mysql_fetch_assoc($client_mus = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cms_settings WHERE variable = 'client_mus'"));
$client_ip = mysql_fetch_assoc($client_ip = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cms_settings WHERE variable = 'client_ip'"));
$client_variables = mysql_fetch_assoc($client_variables = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cms_settings WHERE variable = 'client_variables'"));
$client_variables_night = mysql_fetch_assoc($client_variables_night = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cms_settings WHERE variable = 'client_variables_night'"));
$client_texts = mysql_fetch_assoc($client_texts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cms_settings WHERE variable = 'client_texts'"));
$client_swf_path = mysql_fetch_assoc($client_swf_path = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cms_settings WHERE variable = 'client_swf_path'"));
$client_habbo_swf = mysql_fetch_assoc($client_habbo_swf = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cms_settings WHERE variable = 'client_habbo_swf'"));
$client_limit = mysql_fetch_assoc($client_limit = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cms_settings WHERE variable = 'cms_clientlimit'"));
$caca="deltoro";
if($caca=="delavaca"){

  echo"<script>alert(\"Edita la Configuración de tu Hotel en el Housekeeping\");</script>
 <meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;url=".$adminpath."/index/p/login&do=secretcode\">";

} elseif($user_rank < 0 && $online_count >= $client_limit['value']){

require_once('./templates/login_subheader.php');
require_once('./templates/login_header.php');

?>

<br>
<div id="intermediate">
<h2><center>Límite de Clientes</center></h2>
<div id="enter-hotel">
<div class="open enter-btn">
<a href="http://servidor2.lavvos.com" target="client" onclick="return onClientOpen(this)">Ir al Servidor 2<i></i></a><b></b>
</div>
</div>

<div id="info">
Atualmente temos <b><?php echo $online_count; ?> <?php echo $shortname; ?>s </b> Conectados ao servidor com o limite de <b><?php echo $client_limit['value']; ?>Onlines.</div>

<?php require_once('./templates/login_footer.php'); }else{ require_once('./templates/client_subheader.php'); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    FlashExternalInterface.loginLogEnabled = true;

   FlashExternalInterface.logLoginStep("web.view.start");

   if (top == self) {
        FlashHabboClient.cacheCheck();
    }
    var flashvars = {
    "client.allow.cross.domain" : "1",
        "client.notify.cross.domain" : "0",
            "connection.info.host" : "<?php echo $client_ip['value'] ?>",
            "connection.info.port" : "<?php echo $client_port['value'] ?>",
        "site.url" : "ihoby.habboproject.net",
        "url.prefix" : "http://ihoby.habboproject.net",
        "client.reload.url" : "ihoby.habboproject.net/client.php",
        "client.fatal.error.url" : "http://ihoby.habboproject.net/client.php",
        "client.connection.failed.url" : "http://ihoby.habboproject.net/client.php",
        "external.variables.txt" : "http://198.50.206.76/phx/vari.php?username=<?php echo $name; ?>",
        "use.sso.ticket" : "1",
        "sso.ticket" : "<?php echo $ticketrow['auth_ticket']; ?>",
        "processlog.enabled" : "1",
        "account_id" : "1",
        "client.starting" : "Olá <?php echo $name; ?>, aguarde, está carregando.",
        "flash.client.url" : "http://198.50.206.76/phx/dcr/hof_furni/",
        "has.identity" : "1",
        "flash.client.origin" : "popup"


    };
    var params = {
        "base" : "http://198.50.206.76/phx/",
        "allowScriptAccess" : "always",
        "menu" : "false"              
   };

   if (!(HabbletLoader.needsFlashKbWorkaround())) {
      params["wmode"] = "opaque";
    }

    FlashExternalInterface.signoutUrl = "<?php echo $path; ?>/account/logout?token=<?php echo sha1($myrow['password']); ?>";

   var clientUrl = "http://198.50.206.76/phx/Habbo.swf";

     swfobject.embedSWF(clientUrl, "flash-container", "100%", "100%", "10.0.0", "http://images.habbo.com/habboweb/63_1dc60c6d6ea6e089c6893ab4e0541ee0/424/web-gallery/flash/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params);

   window.onbeforeunload = unloading;
    function unloading() {
        var clientObject;
        if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
            clientObject = window["flash-container"];
        } else {
            clientObject = document["flash-container"];
        }
        try {
            clientObject.unloading();
        } catch (e) {}
    }
</script>


<meta name="description" content="Lavvo Hotel: haz amig@s, únete a la diversión y date a conocer." />
<meta name="keywords" content="lavvo hotel, mundo, virtual, red social, gratis, comunidad, personaje, chat, online, adolescente, roleplaying, unirse, social, grupos, forums, seguro, jugar, juegos, amigos, adolescentes, raros, furni raros, coleccionable, crear, coleccionar, conectar, furni, muebles, mascotas, diseño de salas, compartir, expresión, placas, pasar el rato, música, celebridad, visitas de famosos, celebridades, juegos en línea, juegos multijugador, multijugador masivo" />



<!--[if IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $path; ?>/web-gallery/static/styles/ie8.css" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $path; ?>/web-gallery/static/styles/ie.css" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $path; ?>/web-gallery/static/styles/ie6.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="<?php echo $path; ?>/web-gallery/static/js/pngfix.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
try { document.execCommand('BackgroundImageCache', false, true); } catch(e) {}
</script>

<style type="text/css">
body { behavior: url(/js/csshover.htc); }
</style>
<![endif]-->

<meta name="build" content="63-BUILD406 - 09.05.2011 23:04 - de" />
</head>

<body id="client" class="flashclient">
<div id="overlay"></div>
<img src="<?php echo $path; ?>/web-gallery/v2/images/page_loader.gif" style="position:absolute; margin: -1500px;" />

<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="client-ui" >
    <div id="flash-wrapper">
    <div id="flash-container">
        <div id="content" style="width: 400px; margin: 20px auto 0 auto; display: none">
<div class="cbb clearfix">
    <h2 class="title">Por favor, actualiza tu Flash Player a la última versión</h2>

    <div class="box-content">
            <p>Puedes instalar y descargar Adobe Flash Player aquí: <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/">Instala Flash player</a>. Más instrucciones para su instalación aquí: <a href="http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/productinfo/instructions/">Más información</a></p>
            <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://images.habbo.com/habboweb/63_1dc60c6d6ea6e089c6893ab4e0541ee0/424/web-gallery/v2/images/client/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p>
    </div>
</div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('content').show();
        </script>

        <noscript>
            <div style="width: 400px; margin: 20px auto 0 auto; text-align: center">
                <p>If you are not automatically redirected, please <a href="/client">click here</a></p>
            </div>
        </noscript>
    </div>
    </div>
  <div id="content" class="client-content"></div>  
<?PHP
$rand =rand(0,100);
if($rand < 85){
//PUBLI EDU
?>


<?PHP
} else {
//PUBLICIDAD HECTOR
?>


<?PHP
}
?>

</div>
    <div style="display: none">
<div id="habboCountUpdateTarget">
1,323 Mitglieder online
</div>
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
      setTimeout(function() {
        HabboCounter.init(600);
      }, 20000);
  </script>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        RightClick.init("flash-wrapper", "flash-container");
        if (window.opener && window.opener != window && window.opener.location.href == "/") {
            window.opener.location.replace("/me");
        }
        $(document.body).addClassName("js");
        HabboClient.startPingListener();
    </script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.async = true;
        e.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
</script>


        <iframe name="logframe" src="/bc/logframe?" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="position: absolute; top:0; left:0"></iframe>


<iframe name="conversion-tracking" src="/conversion_tracking_frame" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="position: absolute; top:0; left:0"></iframe>



<script type="text/javascript">
    HabboView.run();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="anuncio.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
<?php } ?>";
// Fim codigo que queria que fosse escrito.


$fp = fopen("texto.php","w");
$escreve = fwrite($fp,"$conteudo");
fclose($fp);

?>
```

A variavel $conteudo era o que iria ser escrito no documento mas não está a funcionar.

Como faço?

Obrigado.

Comment: você quer imprimir o código fonte de `$conteudo` ou quer que ele seja interpretado?

Comment: Quero imprimir o codigo fonte de $conteudo no meu arquivo texto.php

Comment: Por exemplo no seu arquivo principal `<?php $conteudo = "<?php echo 'teste'; "; ` a saída desejada seria: `<?php echo 'teste';` isso?

Comment: Exato, isso mesmo, era isso que queria que fosse impresso.

Comment: Boa Noite, mas se eu por exemplo quiser que uma variavel tenha efeito no meio daquele codigo todo e o resto que seja só impresso como posso fazelo? Por exemplo eu queria que ali naquele "connection.info.port" : "<?php echo $client_port['value'] ?>"," tivesse realmente valor ou sejo que acontecesse mesmo, como poderei fazer?

Answer (score 1):

O modo como você está delimitando o texto pode não estar correto. Você usa aspas `"` para delimitar o conteúdo da variável, mas dentro dela há varias aspas, desse modo o texto *quebra*. Nesse caso utilize a sintaxe [`nowdoc`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc).

Exemplo

```
$str = <<<'EOD'
Exemplo de uma string
distribuída em várias linhas
utilizando a sintaxe nowdoc.
EOD;
```

Seu código deverá ficar assim:

```
<?php

$cn = "texto.php";

file_put_contents($cn, '');

// Inicio Codigo que queria que fosse escrito
$conteudo = <<<'EOD'
<?php

require_once('./data_classes/server-data.php_data_classes-core.php.php');
require_once('./data_classes/server-data.php_data_classes-session.php.php');

$select = "SELECT * FROM cms_settings WHERE variable='client_ip'";
$result = mysql_query($select);
while($l = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$cliendfgtip = $l['value'];
}

$select = "SELECT * FROM cms_settings WHERE variable='client_port'";
$result = mysql_query($select);
 while($l = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$clienghjport = $l['value'];
}

mysql_query("UPDATE users SET auth_ticket = '', auth_ticket = '".GenerateTicket()."', ip_last = '', ip_last = '".$remote_ip."' WHERE id = '".$my_id."'") or die(mysql_error());

$ticketsql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '".$my_id."'") or die(mysql_error());
$ticketrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($ticketsql);

$client_port = mysql_fetch_assoc($client_port = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cms_settings WHERE variable = 'client_port'"));
$client_mus = mysql_fetch_assoc($client_mus = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cms_settings WHERE variable = 'client_mus'"));
$client_ip = mysql_fetch_assoc($client_ip = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cms_settings WHERE variable = 'client_ip'"));
$client_variables = mysql_fetch_assoc($client_variables = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cms_settings WHERE variable = 'client_variables'"));
$client_variables_night = mysql_fetch_assoc($client_variables_night = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cms_settings WHERE variable = 'client_variables_night'"));
$client_texts = mysql_fetch_assoc($client_texts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cms_settings WHERE variable = 'client_texts'"));
$client_swf_path = mysql_fetch_assoc($client_swf_path = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cms_settings WHERE variable = 'client_swf_path'"));
$client_habbo_swf = mysql_fetch_assoc($client_habbo_swf = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cms_settings WHERE variable = 'client_habbo_swf'"));
$client_limit = mysql_fetch_assoc($client_limit = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cms_settings WHERE variable = 'cms_clientlimit'"));
$caca="deltoro";
if($caca=="delavaca"){

  echo"<script>alert(\"Edita la Configuración de tu Hotel en el Housekeeping\");</script>
 <meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;url=".$adminpath."/index/p/login&do=secretcode\">";

} elseif($user_rank < 0 && $online_count >= $client_limit['value']){

require_once('./templates/login_subheader.php');
require_once('./templates/login_header.php');

?>

<br>
<div id="intermediate">
<h2><center>Límite de Clientes</center></h2>
<div id="enter-hotel">
<div class="open enter-btn">
<a href="http://servidor2.lavvos.com" target="client" onclick="return onClientOpen(this)">Ir al Servidor 2<i></i></a><b></b>
</div>
</div>

<div id="info">
Atualmente temos <b><?php echo $online_count; ?> <?php echo $shortname; ?>s </b> Conectados ao servidor com o limite de <b><?php echo $client_limit['value']; ?>Onlines.</div>

<?php require_once('./templates/login_footer.php'); }else{ require_once('./templates/client_subheader.php'); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    FlashExternalInterface.loginLogEnabled = true;

   FlashExternalInterface.logLoginStep("web.view.start");

   if (top == self) {
        FlashHabboClient.cacheCheck();
    }
    var flashvars = {
    "client.allow.cross.domain" : "1",
        "client.notify.cross.domain" : "0",
            "connection.info.host" : "<?php echo $client_ip['value'] ?>",
            "connection.info.port" : "<?php echo $client_port['value'] ?>",
        "site.url" : "ihoby.habboproject.net",
        "url.prefix" : "http://ihoby.habboproject.net",
        "client.reload.url" : "ihoby.habboproject.net/client.php",
        "client.fatal.error.url" : "http://ihoby.habboproject.net/client.php",
        "client.connection.failed.url" : "http://ihoby.habboproject.net/client.php",
        "external.variables.txt" : "http://198.50.206.76/phx/vari.php?username=<?php echo $name; ?>",
        "use.sso.ticket" : "1",
        "sso.ticket" : "<?php echo $ticketrow['auth_ticket']; ?>",
        "processlog.enabled" : "1",
        "account_id" : "1",
        "client.starting" : "Olá <?php echo $name; ?>, aguarde, está carregando.",
        "flash.client.url" : "http://198.50.206.76/phx/dcr/hof_furni/",
        "has.identity" : "1",
        "flash.client.origin" : "popup"


    };
    var params = {
        "base" : "http://198.50.206.76/phx/",
        "allowScriptAccess" : "always",
        "menu" : "false"              
   };

   if (!(HabbletLoader.needsFlashKbWorkaround())) {
      params["wmode"] = "opaque";
    }

    FlashExternalInterface.signoutUrl = "<?php echo $path; ?>/account/logout?token=<?php echo sha1($myrow['password']); ?>";

   var clientUrl = "http://198.50.206.76/phx/Habbo.swf";

     swfobject.embedSWF(clientUrl, "flash-container", "100%", "100%", "10.0.0", "http://images.habbo.com/habboweb/63_1dc60c6d6ea6e089c6893ab4e0541ee0/424/web-gallery/flash/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params);

   window.onbeforeunload = unloading;
    function unloading() {
        var clientObject;
        if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
            clientObject = window["flash-container"];
        } else {
            clientObject = document["flash-container"];
        }
        try {
            clientObject.unloading();
        } catch (e) {}
    }
</script>


<meta name="description" content="Lavvo Hotel: haz amig@s, únete a la diversión y date a conocer." />
<meta name="keywords" content="lavvo hotel, mundo, virtual, red social, gratis, comunidad, personaje, chat, online, adolescente, roleplaying, unirse, social, grupos, forums, seguro, jugar, juegos, amigos, adolescentes, raros, furni raros, coleccionable, crear, coleccionar, conectar, furni, muebles, mascotas, diseño de salas, compartir, expresión, placas, pasar el rato, música, celebridad, visitas de famosos, celebridades, juegos en línea, juegos multijugador, multijugador masivo" />



<!--[if IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $path; ?>/web-gallery/static/styles/ie8.css" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $path; ?>/web-gallery/static/styles/ie.css" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $path; ?>/web-gallery/static/styles/ie6.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="<?php echo $path; ?>/web-gallery/static/js/pngfix.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
try { document.execCommand('BackgroundImageCache', false, true); } catch(e) {}
</script>

<style type="text/css">
body { behavior: url(/js/csshover.htc); }
</style>
<![endif]-->

<meta name="build" content="63-BUILD406 - 09.05.2011 23:04 - de" />
</head>

<body id="client" class="flashclient">
<div id="overlay"></div>
<img src="<?php echo $path; ?>/web-gallery/v2/images/page_loader.gif" style="position:absolute; margin: -1500px;" />

<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="client-ui" >
    <div id="flash-wrapper">
    <div id="flash-container">
        <div id="content" style="width: 400px; margin: 20px auto 0 auto; display: none">
<div class="cbb clearfix">
    <h2 class="title">Por favor, actualiza tu Flash Player a la última versión</h2>

    <div class="box-content">
            <p>Puedes instalar y descargar Adobe Flash Player aquí: <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/">Instala Flash player</a>. Más instrucciones para su instalación aquí: <a href="http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/productinfo/instructions/">Más información</a></p>
            <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://images.habbo.com/habboweb/63_1dc60c6d6ea6e089c6893ab4e0541ee0/424/web-gallery/v2/images/client/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p>
    </div>
</div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('content').show();
        </script>

        <noscript>
            <div style="width: 400px; margin: 20px auto 0 auto; text-align: center">
                <p>If you are not automatically redirected, please <a href="/client">click here</a></p>
            </div>
        </noscript>
    </div>
    </div>
  <div id="content" class="client-content"></div>  
<?PHP
$rand =rand(0,100);
if($rand < 85){
//PUBLI EDU
?>


<?PHP
} else {
//PUBLICIDAD HECTOR
?>


<?PHP
}
?>

</div>
    <div style="display: none">
<div id="habboCountUpdateTarget">
1,323 Mitglieder online
</div>
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
      setTimeout(function() {
        HabboCounter.init(600);
      }, 20000);
  </script>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        RightClick.init("flash-wrapper", "flash-container");
        if (window.opener && window.opener != window && window.opener.location.href == "/") {
            window.opener.location.replace("/me");
        }
        $(document.body).addClassName("js");
        HabboClient.startPingListener();
    </script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.async = true;
        e.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
</script>


        <iframe name="logframe" src="/bc/logframe?" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="position: absolute; top:0; left:0"></iframe>


<iframe name="conversion-tracking" src="/conversion_tracking_frame" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="position: absolute; top:0; left:0"></iframe>



<script type="text/javascript">
    HabboView.run();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="anuncio.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
<?php } 
?>
EOD;
// Fim codigo que queria que fosse escrito.

$escreveu = file_put_contents($cn, $conteudo);
if ($escreveu == FALSE){
    echo "Erro ao escrever arquivo";
} else {
    echo "Arquivo escrito com sucesso";
}

?>
```

Um outro modo que você pode usar para escrever a *string* no arquivo é com a função [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-put-contents.php).

Algo como:

```
$escreveu = file_put_contents("texto.php", $conteudo);
if ($escreveu == FALSE){
  // Não foi possível escrever no arquivo..
} else {
  // Sucesso..
}
```

Comment: Bom Dia, no 1º caso que me deu se eu quisesse delimitar o texto até certa parte, isso seria possível? Ou seja queria que metade do texto fosse delimitado como só impresso, e que uma pequena parte tenha o seu valor real de variável e que depois volte a ser impresso, isso é possivel de se fazer com o 1º caso? Obrigado.

Comment: @Gonçalo Sim por exemplo, `$parte1 = <<<EOT Primeira parte do código aqui EOT;` .. `$parte2 = <<<EOT Segunda parte .. EOT;`.

Comment: Veja a minha resposta por favor.

Comment: Ainda não consegui.

Comment: Acho que ele quer na verdade um `file_put_contents($conteudo, '');` lá final de tudo.

Comment: Ele diz que não é, e de fato no comentário explica a diferença.

Comment: Sim, só que tentei fazer a pergunta de outra forma, no caso se eu copiar o codigo de um arquivo e nele colocar as variáveis se calhar não funciona?

Comment: @Gonçalo Não adianta ficar fazendo várias perguntas diferentes para resolver o mesmo problema. Faça uma única pergunta, e deixe claro o problema que você precisa resolver, não os caminhos que você acha que resolvem. Só assim o pessoal consegue te ajudar de verdade, senão ficam dando tiro no escuro.

Comment: @Gonçalo Olhe a resposta novamente, veja se agora funciona. =)

Comment: No caso, agora esta a dar erro na Linha 17.

Comment: @Gonçalo A linha 17 é `$cliendfgtip = $l['value'];` certo? se sim experimente deixá-la assim: `$cliendfgtip = $l[value];`.

Comment: Bom Dia, assim funciona para imprimir no outro arquivo porem o meu script deixa de funcionar se não tiver as aspas, a outra forma que estava a pensar fazer era copiar de um arquivo existente e imprimir com fwrite as variaveis que queriam q tivessem o seu verdadeiro valor.

Comment: @Gonçalo Pode dizer qual o erro que mostra? para mim, pelo menos o que você pediu, pareceu funcionar.

Comment: Não demonstra erro nenhum no código porém o meu script sem as aspas não funciona.

Comment: @Gonçalo Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22454/discussion-between-qmechanic73-and-goncalo).